# inserting links to ajax control toolkit html editor

Tags: c#, button, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I used following code to simply add the insert link button.

```
   TopToolbar.Buttons.Add(new AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor.ToolbarButton.InsertLink());
```

But I am  facing issues in IE  and Firefox as the insert link box is not appearing at proper place or sometimes it is hiding behind other controls and hence not accessible.

Has any one else faced similar problems?
Is there any other way to add/identify url(s) to the html editor? 
Any help will be appreciated! 
Thanks!

Comment: Strange! I tried your code and didn't face the problem like that. Which are browsers' version you're using? Could I see your aspx code?

Comment: IE 10 and mozilla firefox am facing this issue. this is my aspx code         <custom:MMCEditor runat="server" ID="EditorSummary" Height="300px" Style="border-bottom: #c2c2c2 1px solid;
    padding-top: 5px;" Width="100%" EditorControl="Summary" EnableViewState="false"
    BehaviorID="sumEdit" />

Comment: Oh sorry, I used IE11 and Firefox 26.0, it works fine for these versions. I've tested with IE10 and I got error message from ScriptResource.axd file, the `editor._getSelection() is null and it try to get type from null object`. I'm not sure if this is the same error as you, but the editor works without TopToolbar customization for IE10 and lower.

Comment: I am not getting any error, its only the insert url box which is not appearing at right position (i.e. either its hiding behind other controls or opening up somewhere up in the page). Is it coming up fine for you in all the browsers?

Comment: Yes, they are, the box to insert URL displayed at the right position. I also tested in `Chrome 31.0.1650.63 m`, `Opera 18.0` and `Safari 5.1.7 (7534.57.2)`, it's working fine for them.